# High performance socket server (like MMO)

Tags: c#, performance, sockets, mmo

I'm working on a server project (and I want to make a MMO Server with this). I have created something but IDK is it a good system. Namely is there a MMO server tutorial/book for creating (help!) a high performance socket server (MMO)? I'll send/receive 5kb data to every connected clients (because this is a MMO systems) and server must handle ~2000clients/s. Can anybody show me a good start point?

Comment: You will want to be careful with the garbage collector if performance is a concern.  You might try to avoid dynamic memory allocation after startup when you can.  (In general, I'd recommend against using a garbage-collected environment for this sort of thing.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There: [C# SocketAsyncEventArgs High Performance Socket Code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/83102/C-SocketAsyncEventArgs-High-Performance-Socket-Cod); based on things I have learnt from this (and some other resources) I have written a high performance TCP server which is handling more than 7000 clients.

Edit: Other good .NET code bases I studied to some extend are [fracture (F#)](https://github.com/fractureio/fracture), [SocketAwaitable](https://github.com/safakgur/Dawn.SocketAwaitable) and [SuperSocket](https://github.com/kerryjiang/SuperSocket). I especially like **fracture** because of it's simple (not naive) and smart buffer pool handling but (as the version I've worked with) it does not provide a separate pool for acceptors; which I've done myself easily based on the already provided pool.

Comment: Perfect! Can you tell me some other resources? Or is this enough?

Comment: The essence is described in this article. But based on your project you may need to improvise. For example I had to see is a client (which was a GPS modem connecting me via GPRS on a specific port) was silent for more than 6 minutes, I had to generate an alert and close it's connection. And it was hard because the client was moving and it's IP was changing so I had to close some connections BUT the modem was really sending me data on another IP. You may google for the class but I have not anything special in my mind right now.

Comment: Yes, I can understand this. Algorithm and techniques can be different for program style (usage).

Comment: (I am not a native speaker of English language) I meant no offence! I just described my own project! That's all! I'll be happy to be more helpful. But this was all I remembered on internet. Excuse me again; Please.